# Pass chose value into label inside a table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I'm relatively new into swift and I'm still struggling with some basics. But well thank you all fo helping me in this. Ok when a `UITableViewCell`is selected a `PopUpViewController` is presented with a datepicker so the user can select a desire date and when `dissmisButton`is pressed the current view is dismissed and as soon that happens I want the selected value to show on the label embedded on the selected `UITableViewCell`. 
Code on `PopUpViewController`

```
import UIKit

class PopUpColchonesViewController: UIViewController {

    var tipoColchonArray = [String](arrayLiteral: "Individual", "Matrimonial", "King Size")

    @IBOutlet weak var tipoColchonLb: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipoColchonPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var guardarTipoColchon: UIButton!
    var tipoSeleccionado : String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tipoColchonPicker.delegate = self
        tipoColchonPicker.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func guardarTipo(_ sender: Any) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .guardarTipo, object: nil)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}

extension PopUpColchonesViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return tipoColchonArray.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return tipoColchonArray[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let selectedItem = tipoColchonArray[row]
        tipoSeleccionado = selectedItem

    }
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static let guardarTipo = Notification.Name(rawValue: "guardarTipo")
}
```

What I've try so far

```
  var observer : NSObjectProtocol?

    var cellServicio = UITableViewCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        servicioHogarTB1.delegate = self
        servicioHogarTB1.dataSource = self
        servicioHogarTB1.register(UINib(nibName: "ServicioCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "servicioCell")
        servicioHogarTB1.separatorStyle = .none

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handlePopupClosing), name: .guardarTipo, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if let observer = observer {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
        }
        print(servicioSeleccionado)
    }

    @objc func handlePopupClosing (notification : NSNotification) {
        let tipoVC = notification.object as? PopUpColchonesViewController
        let index = servicioHogarTB1.indexPathForSelectedRow
        if let cell = servicioHogarTB1.cellForRow(at: index!) as? ServicioCell {
            cell.servicioTipoLb.text = tipoVC?.tipoSeleccionado
        }
    }
```

The results so far are error while unwrapping an optional value and the text on label is not shown.

Comment: which line give you error ?

Comment: `if let cell = servicioHogarTB1.ceForRow(at: index!) as? ServicioCell` that's why I change it to optional but still the text on label is not been updated.

Comment: so cell is not of type `ServicioCell` .. do you have other type of cells as well ?

Comment: `servicioHogarTB1` is a cell or tableView  ?

Comment: That's the only custom cell I've so far. The only one with the lable, `servicioTipoLb`

Comment: `servicioHogarTB1` is a tableView

Comment: btw using notification is not a good idea ... you need to use delegate instead ...

Comment: if that cell is not in the view ... it can not get it ... so try one thing ... post your notification after dismiss code ...

Comment: Okay okay thank you for your help, thats so kind. But can you please give my an example or a suggestion of how can I implement that? Please :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like this and check ... hopefully it will work

```
 @IBAction func guardarTipo(_ sender: Any) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .guardarTipo, object: nil)
        })
    }
```